# meteor subscription manager change collection name

Tags: meteor

I'm using subscriptions manager with iron-router and my problem is this one.

I have a collection "participants" with 2 publications: allParticipants and todayParticipants.

if I go to this page:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('winners', {
        waitOn: function () {
            return [subs.subscribe('allWinners'),
                subs.subscribe('allParticipants')];
            console.log("subscribed!");


        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                winners: Winners.find(),
                participants: Participants.find(),
                loginBox: "True"
                }

        }
    });
```

AllParticipants publication is subscribed and put in cache by the subscription manager package.

If after this, I go to this page:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('participants', {
        path: '/',
        waitOn: function () {
            return subs.subscribe('todayParticipants');
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                participants: Participants.find()
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm expecting to subscribe only the todayParticipants but as my subscription is automatically named "Participants", It uses the cached subscription from the previous page being allParticipants.

Is there a way to change the name of my subscriptions in order to have each of them in the right cache?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, there seems to be no solution to this problem.

More explanation here: https://github.com/meteorhacks/subs-manager/issues/11

What I'm doing now is using a very limited number of subscriptions (filtered mainly on user) and then I create as much data objects as I want filtering my subscriptions in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in my waitOn function is first stop my subscriptions like

```
 if (App.subs) {
     for (name in App.subs) {
         App.subs[name].stop();
     }
 }
```

And then I create new subscriptions

```
App.subs = {
    settings: Meteor.subscribe('settings', project), 
    ...
};

return [App.sub.settings, .....];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Sorry to get back to you so lately. If you stop your subscriptions like this, aren't you loosing the advantage of subs? (ie. not having to redownload your subscriptions on each page?). There is not simple way to name your subscriptions accordingly to the publication's name? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you're right. When you stop it, you loose all the data. The subscription manager is the first thing on my todo list!!

Comment: I was wondering if you found a solution yet ? I'm using the subscription manager too now, and have a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825369/subscription-manager-doesnt-update-collection-after-new-subscription)