# Subscription manager doesn't update collection after new subscription

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

In my Meteor application I have this situation in which I have a 'Settings' collection only on the client. So the publish function is:

```
Meteor.publish('settings', function (option) {

    this.added("settings", "settings", {
        bar: true,
        foo: { .... }
    });

    this.ready();
});
```

Initially I subscribe like:

```
waintOn: function () {
    return subs.subscribe('settings')
}
```

But when the route changes I subscribe again like

```
return subs.subscribe('settings', 10);
```

After this I see that the publish function runs, but on the client nothing happens.
For some reason the server thinks that the data did not change and decides to do nothing. So the question is how can I tell Meteor that the data has changed so it sends the data to the client. If the problem is completely different, I'm also very interested!!

UPDATE: the publish function might look like this:

```
Meteor.publish('settings', function (option) {
    var list;

    if (option === 10) {
       list = [1,2,3,4,5];
    }

    this.added("settings", "settings", {
        bar: true,
        foo: list
    });

    this.ready();
});
```

UPDATE2: Expected solution:

```
var isNew = true;
Meteor.publish('settings', function () {

    if(isNew) {
        this.added("settings", "settings", {
            bar: true,
            foo: list
        });
        isNew = false;
    }
    else {
        this.changed('settings', 'settings', {.....});
    }

    this.ready();
});
```

It would even be better if there was a function like `this.exists('settings', 'settings')` because the `isNew` variable feels a bit like a hack!

Anyway, I have it working now as follows:

```
 try { 
     this.removed('settings', 'settings');
 } catch(e){}

 this.added('settings', 'settings', {...});
 ...
```

Comment: What does the `option` parameter do? In other words how different is `subscribe('settings')` from `subscribe('settings', 10)`?

Comment: In my application it means that if the `option` is defined an array is added

Comment: But how this is affecting the data defined in your subscription? Could you please update your question?

Comment: I've updated the question with an example of how `10` effects the output. As you can see I create a useless array, but in my application I load document and extract some data from it

Comment: I found the solution. You cannot use multiple times `added` on the same document (note that 'settings' is the id of this virtual document). Instead you should use `changed` afterwards. I found the solution [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/824)

Comment: Experimentally I came to the same conclusion, however the API still seems broken (or at least not documented correctly). I could only get it to add fields to a document when calling `changed` but I could not modify or remove an existing field. I tried calling `removed` but it usually threw an error. Something about this just doesn't seem right.

Comment: I opened an issue on this [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2321).

Comment: I noticed it too. I've updated my question (see UPDATE 2)